# How to hide a react bell icon without creating a separate component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am trying to show an icon when i double click an element. Here is my project

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-herschel-s092nm?file=/src/App.js

I know there is one option to create another component, but I think that is not necessary, because it is just  a single icon i want to change, is there another simpler way to change the state ?

updated sandbox link

Comment: The sandbox appear to be an react starter template, please update question and link to the project you are working on, and be more specific on the requirement, so we can offer help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```js
import Icon from "/your/Icon/component";

export default function MyApp() {
  const [isIconVisible, setIsIconVisible] = React.useState(false);

  function handleClick(e) {
    if (e.detail === 2) {
      setIsIconVisible(oldState => !oldState);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Show/hide icon</button>
      {isIconVisible && <Icon />}
    </div>
  );
}
```